# waitpid hangs even though child process is dead

Tags: c, shell

i have the following function:

```
int run_func(command history[MAX_INPUT_SIZE], char** args, int capacity) {
    int need_to_wait = 1;
    int i = 0;
    char* arg = args[0];
    int status;
    while (arg != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(arg, "&") == 0) {
            need_to_wait = 0;
            break;
        }
        arg = args[i++];
    }
    pid_t wait_pid;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int res;
    if (pid == 0) {
        res = execvp(args[0], args);
        if (res == -1) {
            printf("exec failed\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (need_to_wait){
            do {
                wait_pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            } while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        }
        history[capacity - 1].pid = pid;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

the issue I have is that the bottom while loop, hangs and doesn't stop whenever I get an invalid command such as 'hello' from the user from the terminal until I press enter again.
this function is being called from another function that receives input from the user.

Comment: The wait code looks fine. What does "until I press enter again" mean? Are you saying it hangs until enter is pressed? Also, suggest you add a print statement after the `waitpid` to confirm whether it has indeed returned or not.

Comment: @kaylum i added printf statements before and after and yes, the wait_pid statement doesn't return until I press enter

Comment: Error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  There's no need to save or test the return value from `execvp()` — if it returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it does not return.  You should almost certainly have an `exit()` or `_exit()` instead of `return 0;` in the error handling code after `execvp()`.  When the command fails (`hello`?), then you end up with two processes running — one from the failed `execvp()` and one the parent process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you!

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @user3629249 I can't post the entire program since it is an assignment and it might be considered cheating if another student uses my entire program as his own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Copying comment into an answer.*</sup>

Side issues:

- Error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`.
- There's no need to save or test the return value from `execvp()` — if it returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it does not return.

Main observation:

- You should almost certainly have an `exit()` or `_exit()` instead of `return 0;` in the error handling code after `execvp()`. When the command fails (`hello`?), then you end up with two processes running — one from the failed `execvp()` and one is the parent process.  This is apt to confuse everything as you have two processes trying to read the terminal at the same time.